# Moving webservice with http and https

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, service, https

I have implemented services calling with **http**.
now services layers is moving to **https**.
At client side do i need to change any thing or 
rename all **url http to https**
Need small clarification on this.

Comment: There is no clarification. You just rename your protocol. You could have easily tried it, before asking on Stackoverflow?

Comment: on server side they installing ssl certificate.  to make data transmission secure. "Https" do i need to any thing on client side in order to send request securely.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special that you need to do. Just change "http://" to "https://" and your connection will be secured by SSL.

You can, optionally, add steps to validate the authenticity of the certificate being used (eg CA validation). But simply adding the "s" will ensure that the traffic is encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change `http` scheme to `https` on client application. The way is that when your client app comes to your `http (80)` port your should redirect it to `https (443)` port by putting `Location` header in HTTP response.

In next versions of your client app you may have to change your protocol directly to `https` in order to avoid unnecessary traffic and server requests.